# How do I implement text streams, similar to cat in unix, in golang?

Tags: unix, go, stream, cat

I would like to implement a version of cat and golang, and modify it to make other useful programs

Answer (score 1):

A cool project you can draw inspiration from is [go-coreutils](https://github.com/ericlagergren/go-coreutils). It has Go implementations of the core GNU command-line utilities like `cat` and many others. [Here is cat](https://github.com/ericlagergren/go-coreutils/blob/master/cat/cat.go), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `os.Open(...)` and `io.Copy(...)` -- but, there's a lot more to it than just that.

Maybe you should really start with the tutorials on https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start u can continue like that and manage flags etc ..

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) == 2 {
        c, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(c))
    } else {
        for {
            var newText string
            fmt.Scanf("%s", &newText)
            fmt.Println(newText)
        }
    }
}
```